# Error building Alamofire and Texture in same Cartfile using Xcode 10.1 + Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, carthage

I have an iOS project that uses both Alamofire and Texture.  I haven't been able to build both at the same time using Carthage and Xcode 10.1.

- With `carthage update --platform ios`, Alamofire fails with "thread-local storage is not supported for the current target"
- With [@Saik0s workaround script](https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/issues/873#issuecomment-386104824), Alamofire fails with no message at all (log below)

Has anyone else had success with Carthage, Alamofire, and Xcode 10.1?

Empty project exhibiting the failure is at [github/kenstir/swift-samples/SadCarthage](https://github.com/kenstir/swift-samples)

**Carthage Output**

```
macken:SadCarthage kenstir$ ./carthage-update 
*** Cloning Alamofire
*** Cloning texture
*** Cloning PINCache
*** Cloning PINRemoteImage
*** Cloning PINOperation
*** Cloning libwebp
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.7.3"
*** Checking out PINCache at "3.0.1-beta.6"
*** Checking out texture at "2.7"
*** Checking out PINRemoteImage at "3.0.0-beta.13"
*** Checking out PINOperation at "1.1.1"
*** Checking out libwebp at "v0.6.0"
*** Downloading PINOperation.framework binary at "Just fixing some warnings"
*** Downloading PINCache.framework binary at "3.0.1-beta.6"
*** Downloading PINRemoteImage.framework binary at "3.0 beta 13: Animated WebP support / better GIF handling"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/r7/c4y6r2q156xbl58p59x61_740000gr/T/carthage-xcodebuild.H7FuEl.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 4:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/kenstir/Documents/xcode/swift-samples/SadCarthage/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Alamofire.xcworkspace -scheme Alamofire\ iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/kenstir/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.1_10B61/Alamofire/4.7.3 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/r7/c4y6r2q156xbl58p59x61_740000gr/T/Alamofire SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/kenstir/Documents/xcode/swift-samples/SadCarthage/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/r7/c4y6r2q156xbl58p59x61_740000gr/T/carthage-xcodebuild.H7FuEl.log
```

**xcodebuild log**

```
macken:SadCarthage kenstir$ cat /var/folders/r7/c4y6r2q156xbl58p59x61_740000gr/T/carthage-xcodebuild.H7FuEl.log
/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/kenstir/Documents/xcode/swift-samples/SadCarthage/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Alamofire.xcworkspace -scheme Alamofire\ iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/kenstir/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.1_10B61/Alamofire/4.7.3 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/r7/c4y6r2q156xbl58p59x61_740000gr/T/Alamofire SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/kenstir/Documents/xcode/swift-samples/SadCarthage/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire)User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /var/folders/r7/c4y6r2q156xbl58p59x61_740000gr/T/Alamofire
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/kenstir/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.1_10B61/Alamofire/4.7.3

Build settings from command line:
    CARTHAGE = YES
    CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
    GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    SDKROOT = iphoneos12.1
    SKIP_INSTALL = YES
    STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT = NO

Build settings from configuration file '/tmp/static.xcconfig.30m4Ve':
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH =
```

**Update**

I took a clue from the above message `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH =` (empty), so I edited the `carthage-update` script like so:

```
--- SadCarthage/carthage-update
+++ SadCarthage/carthage-update
@@ -8,7 +8,8 @@ IFS=$'\n\t'

 xcconfig=$(mktemp /tmp/static.xcconfig.XXXXXX)
 trap 'rm -f "$xcconfig"' INT TERM HUP EXIT
-echo "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = YES" >>$xcconfig
+echo "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES" >>$xcconfig
 export XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="$xcconfig"

+cat $xcconfig
 carthage update --platform ios $@
```

Now it builds!  I'm not convinced this is the final answer but it's working so far for me.